# How to test SMB/CIFS using a Mac OSX 10 client?

Tags: macos, samba, smb, cifs

I could not find any tools that are available to test SMB using a mac client. I would like to test if all the basic functions (read/write/modify) work as expected on the server. I looked at SMBup and its a basic tool that can be used to access the share.

If there is a tool to measure the throughput, verify smb protocol correctness on the server, that would be great. We are planning to use a SMB to host a lot of our content.

Answer (score 1):

Don't rule out the humble and simple time command.  It will tell you how long any command takes a time of a copy from and to the share could be helpful.

```
ojblass@servername:/home/ojblass $ time cp .profile .profile.bak

real    0m0.02s
user    0m0.00s
sys     0m0.00s
```